# PHPMailer works in browser but not working as cron job

Tags: php, email, cron, phpmailer

I have a simple php file that sends an email using PHPMailer.  It works great when run from the browser.
When I try to run it from a cron job I don't get the email.  I have looked for quite a while for an answer here, but I have not been able to get it to work.
Most solution have to do with relative paths in the php code.  I changed the paths on the require lines to be absolute if cron job has a different path.

I am pretty new to all of this, so any help would be appreciated.
I am probably missing something simple.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<?php
/* Namespace alias. */
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

/* If you installed PHPMailer without Composer do this instead: */

require '/hermes/bosnaweb21a/b1837/ipw.whitmerd/public_html/test03/include/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require '/hermes/bosnaweb21a/b1837/ipw.whitmerd/public_html/test03/include/PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require '/hermes/bosnaweb21a/b1837/ipw.whitmerd/public_html/test03/include/PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

echo phpinfo();
echo __DIR__;

// Email the results
$mailSubject = "Email Subject";

// Create the body of the mail
$mailBody = "Body of email";

/* Create a new PHPMailer object. Passing TRUE to the constructor enables exceptions. */
$mail = new PHPMailer(TRUE);

// Configure the mail object for iPower email account
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = "smtp.ipower.com";
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->isHtml(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Encoding = 'base64';
$mail->Username = "validuser";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->setFrom('Example@gmail.com', 'Example Name');
$mail->Subject = $mailSubject;
$mail->addAddress('Example@gmail.com', 'Example Name');
$mail->Body = $mailBody;
$mailSendSuccess = $mail->send();
$mail = null;

// Success or failure message
if ($mailSendSuccess) {
    echo "<br>Email was sent sucessfully.";
} else {
    echo "<br>There was a problem sending the email.";
}
```

I wanted to get the phpinfo() information with the job running from cron job.  So I was trying to create a file in a know location.
I tried this simple file operation that works well from the browser, but not from the cron job.
I commented out the code to grab the phpinfo into a file to just create a dummy file and that is not working.

```
<?php

$tempDir = '/hermes/bosnaweb21a/b1837/ipw.whitmerd/public_html/test03/misc/';
$tempFile = 'phpini_fromcron.html';

$fileContents = dirname(__DIR__);
$fileContents .= '<br>';
$fileContents .= 'Test file contents.';

// ob_start();
// phpinfo();
// $phpini = ob_get_contents();
// ob_end_clean();

// $fileContents .= $phpini;

$createFile = fopen($tempDir . $tempFile, 'w');
if (fwrite($createFile, $fileContents)) {
    echo "File created.";
} else {
    echo "There were problems.";
}
fclose($createFile);
```

Solved, kinda?

Turns out the directory name was the problem.  I don't know what, as the permissions are set the same.

If anyone has a theory as to why, I would love to hear it.

Comment: I remember having a similar issue long time ago and the issue turned out to be with how I was calling the php file from Cron, try to search for something along the lines of "how to run PHP files with Cron"

Comment: Did you check the error logs (server/php)? Did you redirect the script output to some file so that you can check it later?

Comment: Are the permissions correct? It needs to have a minimum value of 755 (the file being executed by cron)

Comment: I think the require paths don't need to be absolute. It should be enough just using the path from the perspective of the file location.

Comment: I have another cron that calls a php using curl and seems to work fine.

Comment: To check things I wanted to get the phpinfo() to a file running from cron and I cannot get that to work either.
```

Comment: How do you run you cron? You should be able to manually run same command that you put in cron

Comment: Justians, I setup the cron through cPanel on my providers site.

Comment: Chryfi, I checked permissions and they are 644 for the .php files.  I changed to 755, but the still no joy.  All the other php files are 644 as well.  Would it run from the browser if the permission was 644?

Comment: It's most likely to be ownership that's causing the problems. You can either loosen permissions (as others have suggested), or (safer) run the cron job as the `www-data` user. `644` permissions is all that you will need to *run* the script (because if you're invoking it via a `php` command, it's not the script itself that needs to executable), but if that script needs to write files (as your example does), then it needs write permissions in the place it's writing to. I'd expect any errors caused by permissions like this should appear in your error logs.

Comment: I changed permissions to 755 on the folder that the file is being written to and on the php file. Still no joy.  Also, nothing showing in the error logs.  Any other ideas.

Comment: are you able to check the system logs and see if the cronjob is actually running? If there is no errors in the error logs I am thinking that the cron is not running.

Comment: I cannot get to the system logs because it is a hosted server.
I cpanel it says the job ran.

Comment: How the cron job is registered? Are you using php-cli or http request?

Comment: I don't understand about how the cron job is registered.  There is a form in CPanel on the host site that allows me to create the cron job.

Comment: I have found something strange.   My test php file was in a directory public_html/test03/php/.  If I move it to another directory like public_html/Dev/ it seems to work.

Comment: Is there a restriction on what the directory names can be for cron?  Could the 03 be a problem or using php as a directory name?  I confirmed that the permissions were the same on the directories.